# How to get odbc driver version? It is confusing?

Tags: postgresql, unixodbc

We use psqlODBC driver through unixODBC driver to access postgres database. The unixODBC version is:

`# odbcinst --version
unixODBC 2.2.14`

So does this mean ODBC version is `v2.0`?

But in psqlODBC code I see that default ODBC version set to `v3.0` (i.e. 0300).

Now I am confused with these versions. Till I was assuming its `v2.0`. How do I know whether I am using ODBC `v2.0` or `v3.0`?

Comment: psqlODBC version is 09.01.0100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using unixODBC version 2.2.14, using psqlODBC (unstated version) [implementing the ODBC v3.0 "standard" protocol/interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC#Version_history).

It's like, say, Firefox version 18 using HTTP/1.1, or PgJDBC 9.4 implementing JDBC4.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I printed the ODBC version within psqlODBC driver code and it implements ODBC v3.51.